# Content loaded under Bootstrap's dropdown selection is stacked one under another instead of side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have two menu selections to compare two graphs side by side. They should be loaded side by side when they are chosen from the dropdown menu, but I don't understand why they are stacked one under the other instead of side by side, even if I specified float left/right for the two columns they should be in. I checked and all tags seem to be closed, they should be in the right place. Everything else works. What is wrong?

The code:

```js
        $('#inlineFormCustomSelect').change(function() {
        $('.child-item').removeClass('show'); // hide all visible
            $('#' + $( this ).val()).addClass('show'); // Show what is necessary
        });

    $('#inlineFormCustomSelect2').change(function() {
    $('.child-item1').removeClass('show1'); // hide all visible
        $('#' + $( this ).val()).addClass('show1'); // Show what is necessary
    });
```

```css
        .child-item {
            display: none
        }
        .child-item1 {
            display: none
        }

        .show {
            display: block
        }
        .show1 {
            display: block
        }

#sinistra {
  float:left;
  width:50%
}
#destra {
  float:right;
  width:50%
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   

    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="sinistra">
    <form>
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto my-1">
                <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Scegli i capitoli da confrontare...</label>
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="1">Capitolo I</option>
                    <option value="2">Capitolo II</option>
                    <option value="3">Capitolo III</option>
                    <option value="4">Capitolo IV</option>
                    <option value="5">Capitolo V</option>
                    <option value="6">Capitolo VI</option>
                    <option value="7">Capitolo VII</option>
                    <option value="8">Capitolo VIII</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                    <div id="1" class="child-item">
                        <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2406500" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2406500/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="2" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527133" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527133/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="3" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527146" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527146/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="4" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527195" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527195/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="5" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527240" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527240/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="6" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527243" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527243/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="7" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527245" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527245/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="8" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527246" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527246/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col" id="destra">
<form>
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto my-1">
            <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect2">Scegli i capitoli da confrontare...</label>
            <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect2">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="1">Capitolo I</option>
                <option value="2">Capitolo II</option>
                <option value="3">Capitolo III</option>
                <option value="4">Capitolo IV</option>
                <option value="5">Capitolo V</option>
                <option value="6">Capitolo VI</option>
                <option value="7">Capitolo VII</option>
                <option value="8">Capitolo VIII</option>
            </select>
            <div>
                <div id="1" class="child-item1">
                    <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2406500" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2406500/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="2" class="child-item1">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527133" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527133/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="3" class="child-item1">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527146" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527146/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="4" class="child-item1">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527195" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527195/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="5" class="child-item1">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527240" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527240/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="6" class="child-item1">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527243" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527243/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="7" class="child-item1">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527245" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527245/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="8" class="child-item1">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2527246" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2527246/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have the same `id` in elements of `child-item` and `child-item1` classes. 
Html attributes `id` should be unique on your page to work correctly.

Just add custom prefixes to the ids of your elements, e.g. *#col1-1, #col1-2, #col1-3, #col2-1, #col2-2, #col2-3*. And fix the corresponding jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

I checked it and it seems to be caused by the col-auto class being used, which leads to both selection menus overlapping on smaller screens. Just using the col class should fix your problem.